# How to create a new variable after comparing values from multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

I have this data frame, q17, below. My goal is replacing "contacts" following these rules:

```
ifelse (any values in q17a, q17d, q17f, q17g <5) then contacts is 1

    ifelse (any values in q17a, q17d, q17f, q17g ==5) then contacts is 0

        ifelse (any values in q17a, q17d, q17f, q17g ==8 or 9 or NA) then contacts is 99
```

`q17[1:6,]`

```
   q17a q17d q17f q17g contacts
1     2    5    2   NA       1
2     5    5    5   NA       0
3     1    5    5   NA       1
4     4   NA    5   NA       1
5     1    5    5    5       1
6     3    5   NA   NA       1
```

I tried the following for example, using the answer provided, but the result is not as I expected. Can somebody suggest how to solve this problem?

```
apply(q17[,colnames(q17)[1:4]], 1, function(df) 
  ifelse(any(df<5), 1, 
      ifelse(any(df==5),0, 
            ifelse(df == 8 & df == 9 & is.na(df)), 99))) 
[1]  1 NA  1  1  1  1
```

I want the result to be: 1  0  1  1  1  1 instead of 1 NA 1 1 1 1

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Most of the values in your data.frame is either 5 or below 5 (the first two conditions). There is no NA, 8 or 9 in the data you showed. In your code you are only using one column (variable) d1$q17d, what about other variables?

Comment: thanks aelwan, I've improved my question by adopting your suggestions. I've transferred NA to "x" and mixed them up in the question originally, which I've fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very confused by your question... exactly as you request this is how you do what you ask, as ordered by your example, not your question.

```
q17 <- data.frame(q17a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), q17d = c(2,5,1,4,1,3,4,5,4,4), q17f = c(2,5,5,5,5,NA,5,1,NA,4), q17g = c(2,5,5,5,5,NA,5,1,NA,4))
```

q17 looks like

```
   q17a q17d q17f q17g
1     1    2    2    2
2     2    5    5    5
3     3    1    5    5
4     4    4    5    5
5     5    1    5    5
6     6    3   NA   NA
7     7    4    5    5
8     8    5    1    1
9     9    4   NA   NA
10   10    4    4    4
```

This is my approach:

```
apply(q17[,colnames(q17)[1:4]], 1, function(df) 
  ifelse(any(df == 8 | df == 9 | is.na(df)), 99, 
         ifelse(any(df == 5), 0, 
                ifelse(any(df < 5), 1))))
```

And the result is:

```
 [1]  1  0  0  0  0 99  0 99 99  1
```

After question edit:

```
apply(q17[,colnames(q17)[1:4]], 1, function(df) 
  ifelse(any(df < 5, na.rm = T), 1, 
         ifelse(any(df == 5, na.rm = T), 0, 
                ifelse(df == 8 & df == 9 & is.na(df), 99))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works! what I was not clear was how to loop. Sorry for the confusion in my original question. I've updated it now.

Comment: Sure thing-- the "apply" family is worth looking up, but you may just want to google some "For Loop" examples in R.

Comment: Hi Evan, I have an issue: when the data is something like this:q17a q17d q17f q17g 
1    2    5    2   NA
2    5    5    5   NA
3    1    5    5   NA
4    4   NA    5   NA
5    1    5    5    5   
6    3    5   NA   NA

Comment: Use dput(q17) and paste the output so that I can run your data ~

Comment: I've edited the questions. now it includes the data and the output

Comment: > dput(q17)
structure(list(q17a = c(2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3), q17d = c(5, 5, 5, 
NA, 5, 5), q17f = c(2, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA), q17g = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5, NA)), .Names = c("q17a", "q17d", "q17f", "q17g"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: See edit at the bottom

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a life saver for me. I've spent so much time battling with this..:)